# Count total guild's bots Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make server info command that also counts bots that are in the current server. I tried doing something like that:

```
@bot.command(name="serverinfo")
async def serverinfo(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.bot_count)
```

But guild object doesn't have attribute bot_count.

Answer (score 2):

`bot_count` is not a predefined attribute to guilds in discord.py so you kind of have to create something for that yourself. This can be done by iterating through all the server members and checking to see if each member is a bot account or not. Below is how I would attempt to do so.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

BOT_TOKEN = "BOT TOKEN HERE"
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$", intents = intents)


@bot.command(name="serverinfo")
async def serverinfo(ctx: commands.Context):
    
    bot_counter = 0
    for member in ctx.guild.members: # Iterate through all the members in the server
        if member.bot: # Checking to see if the member is a bot account or not
            bot_counter += 1

    await ctx.send(bot_counter)

bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Note: In order to use the `guild.members` attribute, you will need to have intents.members enabled on your bot and as well as defined in your code.

You can see all the attributes the guild object allows you to access through discord.py on their [guild object documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild)

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped :D